# Autosaving Jmeter reports summary form non GUI

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for various performance and load tests and would like to save summary of Summary report and aggregate report automatically when test is done.

Usually summary table when you running form GUI looks like this :

*Label | Samples | Average | Min |Max |Error |Throughput |etc.*

1. When I use *Write results to file/ Read form file*  filed , generated report will contain **all http requests** I generate, it can be millions. File would be huge and even then, no summary on the end . **No average time **
2. Same situation for aggregate report, I can not auto generate Summary of aggregate reports same as when you use GUI mode. Saved file contain all requests which is not useful at all.
3. Can I force Jmeter to save those two summaries when test is over ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, don't run your test using GUI. [Run your JMeter test using command-line non-GUI mode](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) as

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results/jtl
   ```
2. Second, disable all the listeners during test run. Once test execution is finished you will be able to open JMeter's GUI, add Listener of your choice to Test Plan or Workbench and use "Browse" button to locate your `results.jtl` file.

   [image: Listener load results]

JMeter cannot display **only** summary as all the "Total" fields are being calculated.

- № Samples - is count of all executed requests
- Average - is arithmetical mean of all requests time (sum of all samples elapsed time divided by count)
- etc. See [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for metrics explanation

So you got the idea right, it is better to store the necessary minimum, but you need to store something in order to be able to perform results analysis.

You can control what to store by amending properties which names start with `jmeter.save.saveservice.`. See *jmeter.properties* file in bin folder of your JMeter installation for the details.